# Are there any implementations of Cook-Levin?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, software, cook-levin

Does anyone know if there is an implementation of Cook-Levin?
A program that gets an input like the following:

- $M$: the code of a machine model/simple program in a programming language like C,
- $\vec{n}$: binary integers for the size of the inputs (in bits),
- $t$: a binary integer as a bound on the number of steps (if it is needed),
- $m$: a binary integer as a bound on the amount of memory (if it is needed),

and outputs a Boolean circuit $C$ that computes $M$ on inputs of size $\vec{n}$?

Or a compiler from simple programs in a language like C to Turing machines,
plus an implementation of Cook-Levin for Turing machines.

By a simple program in C I mean a program that does not use libraries
(using standard computational libraries can be fine), i.e.
computes a function of its inputs and
does not interact with the environment (file system, network, other processes, ...).

---

#### Motivation:

Sometimes we want to turn instances of other NP problems into SAT instances
so we can run SAT solvers on them.
In place of writing a reduction program for each NP problem
we can use an implementation of Cook-Levin plus the code of a verifier for the NP problem.

Comment: You can look at some (advanced) tools that translates CSP instances to SAT (e.g. stp, sugar, csp2sat4j, FznTini, Spec2SAT, Bee); encoding a problem using a Constraint Programming language is not as easy as writing a small  verifier program in C, but it's surely easier than encoding directly the SAT instances (a few times I wrote an high-level program that converts a problem instance into a CSP intance and then use one of the above tools to get a CNF file). I think (but I'm not an expert) that the Cook-Levin approach would introduce too-much complexity and lead to unmanageable long formulas.

Comment: Thanks @Marzio. By any chance, do you know if there is any program that can translate (sharply) bounded arithmetic formulas to Boolean circuits?

Comment: sorry, no; the above programs use CNF format as intermediate files

Comment: What format do you want the output in? Presumably a standard *compiler* (which compiles C code to the "Turing machine" assembly code) isn't what you're looking for, or you wouldn't have asked the question...

Comment: @Joshua, I want CNF formulas as the final output 
(or at least Boolean circuits). A compiler from C to any format of Turing machines (or any other machine model) is fine as long as there is also an implementation of Cook-Levin for that format. (I will probably write one if I see there is not a clean open-source implementation.)

Comment: This question is off-topic for cstheory.  It is not a *research-level* question in *theoretical* computer science.  Please the FAQ and the help center for more information.  You might consider stackoverflow.com for programming questions.

Comment: @Philip White, it is not off-topic. As discussed before and you can see in the wiki of [tag:software] tag asking for software related TCS research are on-topic.

Comment: @PhilipWhite when you are unsure about an user's intentions with a question, a good way to orient yourself is to check their history of contributions. From looking at Kaveh's previous posts, it is relatively clear that he is not a crank and probably not asking the question in bad faith. As such, your rude comments are completely unjustified (and I will delete them) and I would urge you to be more constructive with your continued feedback.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev:  Certainly faith  is not what I was concerned with.  I think you missed my point.  Certainly it is possible to ignore comments oe disagrees with..